# from console application to windows form GUI problem

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

i wrote a console application in visual c++, and now i want to add a GUI to it using windows form. I am new to Windows form. and i have following questions

1. I dont know how to include classes from other .h files in windows form.
2. is library like `#include <stdio.h>`, `#include <stdlib.h>`, `#include <iostream>` in my original project still can be used in windows form project?
3. is it better to convert my original project to .dll and use it in windows form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great article from Microsoft about this subject, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290064(VS.71).aspx.

1) I did not understand your question here, but i'm pretty sure you will find the answer in the article above.

2) I don't see why you can't use your original project, so it should probably not be a problem.

3) It depends on the project. DLL files are quite nifty if you want to share the program-code with other applications. But if your program is quite large, then probably no.

Comment: for the 1st question. i mean in c i can just use #include "blabla.h"
but when i tried in windows form. i got  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'namespace'
for the line 
"#include "TDMS.h"

namespace TDMSplotting {...}"

Comment: @Grey, that generally means you messed up something in the class header, like forgot a trailing ; at the end of the class declaration.  #include works the same in any kind of app.

Comment: you are quite right. i forget ; at the end. when i change my main.c to clas.

Answer (score 1):

If you put exactly as is at the very top of your source file: #include

Then you should be able to use windows functions and declarations, I hope this helps.